# Squish test_suite Java Error "Cannot determine URI for '/suite_first/suite_first/tst_case1/test.js'."

Tags: java, linux, squish

I am trying to configure squish on my Linux debian VM running on Windows7 Host PC.
Previously it was running correctly I was able to record the AUT and scripts got generated. But when I restarted my VM suddenly this error started to come and I'm not able to resolve it. Please refer the Link.

[image]

Also as I start the sqishide it gives me the following warning:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
>   MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

can anyone help me how to rectify the issue

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you upgraded Java and did not configure Squish to use the newer version so it is still configured for the older version of Java.

Using the command-line too 'squishconfig --java=/path/to/java' will fix this.
Or, you can reinstall Squish and point it to the newer version of Java during install process.